# I can't add document.querySelector().addEventListener() more than 2

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm using sweetalert ver2 and I want to put several buttons in a page that when each one clicked run that specific js sweetalert code that's refer to it.

the way I do it I make a button with an ID:

```
   <button id="test1">TEST 1 </button>
   <button id="test2">TEST 2 </button>
   and it goes on to several buttons...
```

and then I use a querySelector like this:

```
document.querySelector('#test1').addEventListener('click',runTestOne);
document.querySelector('#test2').addEventListener('click',runTestTwo);
and it goes for other buttons...
```

And sweetalert js code is

```
function runTestOne () {
  swal({
    html:
    '<p>TEST1 CONTENT</p>'
  });
}
function runTestTwo () {
      swal({
        html:
        '<p>TEST2 CONTENT</p>'
      });
    }
and other sweetalert functions for other buttons...
```

so I want to add more of these codes and use several button for different purposes but if I add more than 2 button with same pattern of codes it doesn't work.
What is going wrong?

one more thing I used window.onload and put 2 of querySelector inside it and one outside it worked but in I add another button It won't work.

Comment: you're using unique ids for the buttons right?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in jsfiddle, see if you can reproduce it in jsfiddle. Here's what I have based on the information you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/0vb5npeq/

Comment: you're doing it exactly like I did but why the way you did workes?!

Comment: @mohammadhoseinabbasi Please [edit] your question and show where and how you load your scripts. Where are all the relevant `<script>`s in relation to your HTML? What attributes do they have? Are you waiting for the DOM to be loaded? Keep in mind that JSFiddle will automatically execute JS code _after_ the DOM is done loading. Your code might not do that. You say that more than two buttons don’t work, yet you never show us the code for your third button.

Comment: all other code have the same pattern the content only changes

Comment: Have you opened the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors? If your code truly followed the same pattern, then there would be no problem and there woudn’t be a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it with separating each java-script sweet-alert code in `<script></script>`   s